# How to run conemu inside spacemacs (emacs)?

Tags: emacs, conemu

I am trying to replace windows shell terminal which is run from inside spacemacs with

`SPC a s i`

I have this in my .spacemacs file

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "D:/Program Files (x86)/ConEmu/ConEmu.exe")
(setq shell-file-name "conemu")
(setq explicit-conemu-args '("--noediting" "--login" "-i"))
(setenv "SHELL" shell-file-name)
```

When i run `SPC a s i`, i get a popup window with

[image]

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Check full ConEmu command line in Task manager.

Comment: @Maximus What do you mean?

Comment: Exactly what I've written. You are trying to run ConEmu with wrong arguments and the error box says that clearly. More, it gives you a [link](https://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html) with description and examples. And you may check what do you run (Command line) in the Task Manager.